# Appending to dictionary with loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I want to create a dictionary with a predetermined list, however, I can't seem to figure it out how to avoid overwriting instead of appending, and I'm not sure if I can avoid importing any other modules.

The scope is that I have a data frame of 1 column of character names with ID numbers attached to the names from reading an excel file in, `sega_df`:

```
          Character
0         Amy (335)
1       Tails (359)
2      Shadow (357)
3      Shadow (357)
4       Blaze (337)
```

Then I have a list of all the characters, `characters`, without their ID numbers:

```
['Sonic', 'Knuckles', 'Tails', 'Amy', 'Cream', 'Shadow', 'Rouge', 'Silver', 'Blaze']
```

I want to create a dictionary so I can replace `sega_df.Character`'s by slicing each row entry with the `len()` of the characters in `characters`, producing `desired_sega_df`:

```
         Character
    0          Amy
    1        Tails
    2       Shadow
    3       Shadow
    4        Blaze
```

The dictionary I want to create will have keys of the characters names without their ID numbers, and values of the `len()` of their names. The dictionary is `slice`:

```
{'Sonic': 5, 
 'Knuckles': 8, 
 'Tails': 5, 
 'Amy': 3, 
 'Cream': 5, 
 'Shadow': 6, 
 'Rouge': 5, 
 'Silver': 6, 
 'Blaze': 5}
```

Even when I use `.update()` it still repeatedly overwrites with only `Blaze` as the key and `5` as the value.

```
>>> for character in characters:
...     slice = {character: len(character)}
...     slice.update({character:len(character)})
...
>>> slice
{'Blaze': 5}
```

My question is: *How can I modify my loop to add key-value pairs of all the characters to `slice` rather than continuously overwriting them?*

Comment: Just move `slice = {}` *outside* the loop? Why create and update the same dictionary on each iteration?

Comment: remove `slice={character:len(character)}` and before loop starts add `slice = dict()`

Comment: You are creating a new dictionary each time. `slice = {...}` assigns a new dictionary object to `slice`. Don't do that. And don't use `dict.update()` to add one key-value pair to a dictionary. Create an empty dictionary **once**, outside the loop. In the loop, add a key-value pair with `slice[character] = len(character)`.

Comment: Not that any of what you are doing can't be done more simply by using splitting. None of your names contain whitespace, so you can just use `sega_df['Character'] = sega_df['Character'].str.split().str[0]`

Comment: This seems to be one of the most common beginner mistakes in many programming languages, initializing the collecttion variable each time through a loop instead of before it. I wish I understood the thinking that leads to it, and how programming education could be improved to avoid it.

Comment: @Barmar  and all -- I'll admit, I am still a beginner, practicing programming outside of classes for acadmic and professional skills and fun. I'm not sure if it's common among other beginners like myself, but I never thought of creating an empty variable before loops -- I first interpreted it as an extra step (when I want to limit the number of steps). Initializing works though, and now I see it's important to add this to my understanding. Also, I first tested the loop without the second indented line, and added `.update()` thinking I would keep adding to it. Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your code to :

```
>>> slice = dict()
>>> for character in characters:
...     slice.update({character:len(character)})
...
```

Comment: Why does everyone use `dict.update()` to add a single key-value pair all the time? Just use `slice[character] = len(character)`.

Comment: I agree, we can use both `update` and `assign` even for the single key-value pair. And also, `update` is lot lot slower than `assign`, but OP used update. To make it clear for him, I followed same style.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Pandorable solution. For splitting `Character`, you have a choice of splitting on whitespace or slicing on character count. Which works best depends on your dataset.

Whether you choose the pure Python or Pandas solution, you do not need to use an explicit loop.

```
# remove last 6 characters to leave names
df['Character'] = df['Character'].str[:-6]  # or, df['Chracter'].str.split().str[0]

# calculate length in new series
df['Length'] = df['Character'].map(len)

# convert to dictionary
d = df.set_index('Character')['Length'].to_dict()

print(d)

{'Amy': 3, 'Tails': 5, 'Shadow': 6, 'Blaze': 5}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Pandas approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `slice` as an empty dictionary outside of your loop. As it currently stands, you redefine the dictionary for each character as you iterate.

Answer (score 0):

```
characters = ['Sonic', 
 'Knuckles', 
 'Tails', 
 'Amy', 
 'Cream', 
 'Shadow', 
 'Rouge', 
 'Silver', 
 'Blaze']

slice = {}

for character in characters:

    slice[character]=len(character)

print(slice)
# TH OUTPUT WILL BE THIS : 
# {'Sonic': 5, 'Knuckles': 8, 'Tails': 5, 'Amy': 3, 'Cream': 5, 'Shadow': 6, 'Rouge': 5, 'Silver': 6, 'Blaze': 5}
# IF YOU WANT TOI GET THE USER INPUT CHARACTERS JUST USE OTHER 
#LOOPS TO HOW MUCH YOU WANT TO GIVE 
# THE SOLUTION OF ABOVE QUESTION IS THIS
```